# How to substract or add X days from given date with a formated output?

Tags: bash, date, date-format

I did the following function:

```
#!/bin/bash

function calc_date(){
  odate=$1
  op=$2
  days=$3

  echo $(date "--date=$odate $op $days day" +%d%m%y) 
}
```

And if I call it like this:

```
mydate=$(calc_date '2014-02-22' '+' '2')
echo "$mydate"
```

Returns:

```
240214
```

Now I'm trying to get the same output calling the function by this way:

```
mydate=$(calc_date '220214' '+' '2')
echo "$mydate"
```

How could I format the date passed as parameter to the function to `ddmmyy` format?

Comment: Your script works fine for me, just call it with a different syntax: `calc_date 2014-02-22 - 2` - or alternatively, parse `$1` from your preferred format into `YYYY-mm-dd` format before doing the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, question updated! :)

Comment: It's somewhat annoying changing the question in the way that the topic changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clearest solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

function calc_date(){
  odate=$(date -d "$1" +%d%m%y)
  op=$2
  days=$3

  echo $(date "--date=$odate $op $days day" +%d%m%y) 
}
```

Example:

```
mydate=$(calc_date '220214' '-' '2')
echo "$mydate"

mydate=$(calc_date '220214' '+' '3')
echo "$mydate"
```

Result:

```
200214
250214
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing that `date` does not interpret `220214` correctly. It is interpreted as `2022-02-14` (and not as `2014-02-22`).

One solution is to change or adapt your format:

```
$ date --date "2014-02-12 2 days ago"
Mon Feb 10 00:00:00 CET 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

To reformat a date:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function calc_date(){
    odate=$(echo $1 | sed -r 's/(..)(..)(..)/\3\2\1/')
    op=$2
    days=$3

    echo $(date "--date=$odate $op $days day" +%d%m%y) 
}
```

Here `sed` is simply matching 6 characters in groups of 2, then printing them back out in reverse order. So 220214 becomes 140222. This works properly with `date`, which recognises 6-character numerical date strings as being `YYmmdd`.

Answer (score 0):

If your date is going backwards (i.e. your $op is negative) you will need to put the word "ago" after the "2 day"

```
date --date='2 day ago'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is also you can try.

```
#!/bin/bash

DAYS=2

CURRENTDATE="$(date +%Y%m%d)"

echo "$CURRENTDATE"

OLDERDATE="$(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "$DAYS  days ago ")"

echo "$OLDERDATE"
```